# Efficient way to inter-lay zero rows into a Matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a large matrix in MATLAB and I want to interlay rows and columns of zeroes between the existing rows of the Matrix. I want to go from (a small example of 3x3)

```
[1 2 3; 
 4 5 6; 
 7 8 9]
```

to

```
[1 0 2 0 3;
 0 0 0 0 0 
 4 0 5 0 6;
 0 0 0 0 0;
 7 0 8 0 9]
```

I understand that this can easily be done using for loops, however, I wanted to avoid using a for loops since they are known to be slow in MATLAB.

In my experience, there is usually a nice way to manipulate Matrices in MATLAB and was wondering if there is a simple solution here.

The application I am looking for is enlarging an image matrix using this form and then filling in the zeroes using interpolation.

Comment: You can use `interp2` or `interpn` to interpolate, you don’t need to do this “manually”.

Comment: Yes I know, but I am required to as part of an assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use indexed assignment:

```
a=...
[1 2 3; 
 4 5 6; 
 7 8 9];
result(1:2:2*size(a,1)-1, 1:2:2*size(a,2)-1) = a;
```

Here a variable `result` is created and its odd indices is filled.

Other option:

```
result2 = zeros(2*size(a)-1);
result2(1:2:end,1:2:end) = a;
```

Comment: Thank you I did not know about indexed assignment. I think you meant `2*size(a) - 1` in the last line. Could you change that, since tiny edits are not allowed